# A Code to $_REQUEST in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In Codeigniter,

- `$something = isset($_POST['something']) ? $_POST['something'] : NULL;` **equal to** `$this->input->post('something')`;
- `$something = isset($_GET['something']) ? $_GET['something'] : NULL;` **equal to** `$this->input->get('something')`;

Is there equal code to  `$something = isset($_REQUEST['something']) ? $_REQUEST['something'] : NULL;` ?

Answer (score 1):

for `REQUEST` method in Codeigniter you have to use like describe below.

```
$this->input->get_post('some_data');
```

Let me know if it not works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow methods

1. `$this->input->get_post('some_data');` [Read more](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get_post)
2. `$this->input->post_get('some_data');` [Read more](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post_get)